# Item "AdminBundle\Entity\Prize:000000046fa222" has been successfully created

Tags: sonata

hi i want with sonata to have an item using 'name' label.
but not always the same.

i put this in admin class

```
public function toString($object) {
    if (!is_object($object)) {
        return '';
    }
    if (method_exists($object, '__toString') && null !== $object->__toString()) {
        return (string) $object;
    }

    $cname = explode('\\', get_class($object));
    return end($cname);
}
```

but it give always the same name. i want to have the label 'name' of each entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `__toString()` magic method in your entity class

```
public function __toString(){
    return $this->name;    
}
```

Comment: Can you help me on my second question too ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get name of each entity, use:

```
public function __toString() {
    return self::class;
}
```